# Postgres JSON Output

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a query that outputs:-

```
indicator1,company1,value1
indicator1,company2,value2
indicator1,company3,value3
indicator2,company1,value4
indicator2,company2,value5
indicator2,company3,value6
....
```

How can I transform this output to the following json structure:-

```
{
 indicator1 :{
              "companies" : ["company1","company2","company3"],
              "values"    : ["value1","value2","value3"]
             },
 indicator2 :{
              "companies" : ["company1","company2","company3"],
              "values"    : ["value4","value5","value6"]
             }
}...
```

I'm using postgres 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_json()`, `json_build_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and [`json_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
with q1 as (
    select * from 
        (values 
            ('indicator1', 'company1', 'value1'),
            ('indicator1', 'company2', 'value2'),
            ('indicator1', 'company3', 'value3'),
            ('indicator2', 'company1', 'value4'),
            ('indicator2', 'company2', 'value5'),
            ('indicator2', 'company3', 'value6')
        ) alias(ind, comp, val)
    ),
q2 as (
    select ind, to_json(array_agg(comp)) companies, to_json(array_agg(val)) "values"
    from q1
    group by 1
    order by 1
    ),
q3 as (
    select companies, "values"
    from q2
    ),
q4 as (
    select json_build_object(ind, row_to_json (q3)) obj
    from q2
    join q3 on q2.companies::text = q3.companies::text and q2."values"::text = q3."values"::text
    )
select json_agg(obj)
from q4;
```

Alternative compacted solution, which avoids the clumsy join condition:

```
with q1 as (
    select * from 
        (values 
            ('indicator1', 'company1', 'value1'),
            ('indicator1', 'company2', 'value2'),
            ('indicator1', 'company3', 'value3'),
            ('indicator2', 'company1', 'value4'),
            ('indicator2', 'company2', 'value5'),
            ('indicator2', 'company3', 'value6')
        ) alias(ind, comp, val)
    ),
q2 as (
    select ind, to_json(array_agg(comp)) companies, to_json(array_agg(val)) "values"
    from q1
    group by 1
    order by 1
    )
select json_agg(
    json_build_object(
        ind, 
        json_build_object(
            'companies', companies, 
            'values', "values")
        )
    )
from q2
```